# Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files: PYTHON_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)

Tags: software-installation, compiling, cmake

For the past day and a bit I have been trying to install CERN's root program on Xubuntu (16.04.1) following their README (https://github.com/root-project/root/blob/master/README.md).

I am doing everything in my home folder (I hope this is not a problem), but when I type:

```
$ cmake ../root
```

After about a minute of cmake running it will return the following error:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
     PYTHON_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
linked by target "PyROOT" in directory /home/MYNAME/root/bindings/pyroot
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want one of their prebuilt binaries?

Comment: @roaima Those exist and I won't have to build them? I checked their website just now and it seems you are right but I tried following this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file

to no avail though. I try using "./configure" but it doesn't work. Neither does make. There is no makefile and no such file.

Comment: If you're trying to configure a package you've downloaded source (again).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use the prebuilt packages available from https://root.cern/content/release-61206 and side-step all the problems you're having trying to build the package from source.

Comment: As in the comments before, I get a tar.gz and then I have no idea how to install it from that. I tried following the link provided in my comment and again, encounter the issue where after extraction none of the commands suggested work. Could you elabourate on what I have to do after downloading this file?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the `README` file?